# How can I reuse code in a UFT API script in other API scripts?

Tags: c#, hp-uft, hp-alm

For my UFT API script, i have created a code with a function that obtains a random NIF(Identity ID).

I want to use this code in other api scripts that uses a NIF.

The code I have created is programmed in C#, and I have saved it in the usercode folder(in a file with extension .cs), so that it is accessible by all the activities of my script.
with the rest of my scripts, in the same way that function libraries are shared in GUI type scripts of UFT. But I can't find a way to save the code in ALM.

All my scripts are stored in ALM (application lifecycle management), and to reuse the code I had thought about storing the .cs file also in ALM and associating it.

I want to store the file in ALM or find any other way to share functions in UFT API scripts.